# How to connect Redux containers in my library to the store owned by the application using my library?

Tags: redux

I am creating a npm module that uses Redux for state management.  My module will be a library that is re-used across a couple of applications belonging to different customers.  I hope that the client applications will maintain a single store that my library will also use.

The problem is regarding the `mapStateToProps` function that I need to pass to `connect()` inside my library.  I do not know which key the user of my library has placed my reducers and state tree.

I could make a sensible guess, such as the camelCase name of my library.  However that does not seem a robust approach, because 1/ the user might be using my key for something else and 2/ there could only ever be 1 instance of my library in the state tree (I can think of a few scenarios where I would want more than 1 instance).

Here is a simple example of the problem.  I could create a Logon npm module that I wish to hook into my store and view hierarchies.  I don't know the path within the application store, hence the ???? in mapStateToProps.  Is there a nice way to deal with this situation?

```
// node_modules/my-company-logon/

const LoginScreen = ({ username, failureReason }) => (
    // my presentation logic
);

export default connect(
  username: state.????.lastSessionUsername,
  failureReason: state.????.failureReason
)(LoginScreen); 

export const logonReducer(state, action) => { /* reducer logic */  }




// my-customer/app.js

import LogonScreen, { logonReducer } from 'my-company-logon';

let store = createStore(combineReducers({
    someUnexpectedPath: logonReducer
}))
```

EDIT:

I've sort of solved it by wrapping the connect function of react-redux. The Root component of the module has the context of selectors that can read data from the place where the lib was mounted.

```
export default connect(
    (state, selectors, actionCreators) => ({
        username: selectors.getUsername(state),
        loginFailureReason: selectors.getLogonFailureReason(state)
    })
)(LoginScreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach I've seen used by Redux-dependent libraries is to require the user to add the library's reducer at a known top-level state key, like `combineReducers({myLib : myLibReducer})`.  That works, but is obviously somewhat limiting.

Another option would be to provide some initialization function that would allow the user to pass in the key name, and have your lib use that to set up your selectors appropriately.  You might want to read through some of the articles on selector encapsulation in the [Redux Architecture#Encapsulation](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-architecture.md#encapsulation-and-reusability) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links), particularly Randy Coulman's articles on ["encapsulating the Redux state tree"](http://randycoulman.com//blog/2016/09/13/encapsulating-the-redux-state-tree/).  Finally, you might browse the source for some of the [Redux-connected component libs](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/widgets.md) I have listed as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am trying to achieve the import, configure and use workflow for modules.  With thanks to your comment I have come to a solution that works by creating selectors after the import and configure.  The only problem is the boilerplate, because connected components are doubley decorated on export.

Comment: I wrapped react-redux's connect function so that I could pass in some context to my lib.  I edited my question